# If $X$ is Lindelof and Countably compact, then $X$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Prove:If $X$ is Lindelof and Countably compact, then $X$ is compact.

Attempt: This seems very simple. Let $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \Gamma}$ be an open cover of $X$. Then since $X$ is Lindelof there is a countable subcollection $\{U_{\alpha_i}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ of elements from $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \Gamma}$, covering $X$. Since $X$ is countably compact, there is a finite subcollection $\{U_{\alpha_{i_1}},...,U_{\alpha_{i_n}}\}$ of $\{U_{\alpha_i}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ covering $X$.

Comment: Yes, this follows as easily as night follows day.

Comment: Long ago, when the term "compact" was used only in metric spaces, it meant what we now call "countably compact".  In 1929, in a famous paper, Alexandroff & Hopf investigated various concepts in topological spaces (not mere metric spaces).  They proposed the term "bicompact" for "every open cover has a finite subcover" because it combined both of the properties mentioned here.  And, indeed, the term "bicompact" is still used in Russian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it *is* indeed this easy. These concepts are a natural "decomposition" of compactness into two properties that are both implied by compactness and together imply compactness again (but are individually weaker than compactness). Another one in that holds in metric spaces (and more generally in uniform spaces) is: $X$ is compact iff $X$ is totally bounded and complete. That proof is not quite as trivial as this one. Or $X$ is compact Hausdorff iff $X$ is $H$-closed and regular. Or $X$ is compact Hausdorff iff its is pseudocompact and realcompact.

Same proof without indices: let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of $X$, then by Lindelöfness we have a countable subcover $\mathcal{U}'\subseteq \mathcal{U}$ and by countable compactness we have a finite $\mathcal{U}'' \subseteq \mathcal{U}'$ still with $\bigcup \mathcal{U}'' = X$. Clearly $\mathcal{U}'' \subseteq \mathcal{U}$ and we're done.